# Evaluating $\int_{1/4}^{1/\pi}\left\lfloor\frac{2}{x}\right\rfloor \text{dx}$

Tags: integration, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'd like to get some help in solving this floor function as the rest of the internet doesn't seem to be very helpful.

$$\int_{1/4}^{1/\pi}\left\lfloor\frac{2}{x}\right\rfloor \text{dx}$$

What really stumped me, is the floor function. I can't wrap my head around that and need help explaining why it works. I have seen a couple of videos dealing with functions that aren't in the denominator, but this confuses me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Have you seen what the graph of the integrand looks like?

Comment: I have seen the graph, but I don't understand the intuitive process behind calculating this. Do I merely add the integers I get together or am I not supposed to subtract anything?

Answer (score 2):

For $x\in\left(\frac 14,\frac 27\right)$, $\left\lfloor\frac 2x\right\rfloor=7$. For $x\in\left(\frac 27,\frac 2{2\pi}\right)$, $\left\lfloor\frac 2x\right\rfloor=6$. If you can visualize this, then I think you can find the answer :)

Comment: I am still confused. Say the integrand function was $\lfloor\frac{3}{x}\rfloor$ instead. Would I simply be summing the integers I get from the intervals?

Comment: Yes, the final calculations is summing the integers (multiplied by the length of the intervals). This is because the floor function is a staircase function. It's normal if the calculation seems a bit simple.

Comment: @magamanmagama if you look at the graph of that function, for example between 0.5 and 1.2 (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=floor%28+3%2Fx+%29+from+0.5+to+1.2 ), you will find that the graph "makes four steps down," so in this case you would need to sum the areas of the four adjacent rectangles you obtain from the area under the graph from 0.5 to 1.2. Maybe you should try to do this by hand and check if you get the correct answer (which is 2.25).

Answer (score 1):

$${I}=\underset{\mathrm{1}/\mathrm{4}} {\overset{\mathrm{1}/\pi} {\int}}\lfloor\frac{\mathrm{2}}{{x}}\rfloor{dx} \\ $$
$$\left[\lfloor\frac{\mathrm{2}}{\mathrm{1}/\pi}\rfloor;\lfloor\frac{\mathrm{2}}{\mathrm{1}/\mathrm{4}}\rfloor\right]=\left[\mathrm{6};\mathrm{8}\right] \\ $$
$$\lfloor\frac{\mathrm{2}}{{x}}\rfloor=\mathrm{6}\Rightarrow{x}=\left[\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\pi};\frac{\mathrm{2}}{\mathrm{7}}\right) \\ $$
$$\lfloor\frac{\mathrm{2}}{{x}}\rfloor=\mathrm{7}\Rightarrow{x}=\left[\frac{\mathrm{2}}{\mathrm{7}};\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{4}}\right) \\ $$
$$\lfloor\frac{\mathrm{2}}{{x}}\rfloor=\mathrm{8}\Rightarrow{x}=\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{4}} \\ $$
$${I}=\mathrm{6}\left(\frac{\mathrm{2}}{\mathrm{7}}−\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\pi}\right)+\mathrm{7}\left(\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{4}}−\frac{\mathrm{2}}{\mathrm{7}}\right) \\ $$
$${I}=\frac{\mathrm{41}}{\mathrm{28}}−\frac{\mathrm{6}}{\pi} \\ $$